# Não consigo informar que nenhum resultado foi encontrado dentro de uma pesquisa/filtro em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando o código abaixo para filtrar valores dentro de uma tabela. Usava um código parecido para filtrar itens em uma lista e exibir uma div caso nenhum resultado fosse encontrado. Entretanto, não consigo exibir essa div se eu usar o código abaixo. Já tentei usar `document.getElementById('not-found').style.display = 'block';` usando uma variável com valores booleanos, mas, até o momento, não tive êxito.

Como proceder neste caso?

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr:not(:first)');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase().split(' ');
  
  $rows.hide().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var textN = text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    var matchesSearch = true;
    $(val).each(function(index, value) {
      matchesSearch = (!matchesSearch) ? false : ~textN.indexOf(value) || ~text.indexOf(value);
  });

        return matchesSearch;
    
  }).show();
  
});
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

#not-found {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autofocus type="text" id="search" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  
  <tr id='not-found'><td colspan="2">Nenhum resultado foi encontrado.</td></tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar a primeira linha (#not-found"), você precisa saber quantos elementos o filtro retornou.
Caso esse número seja 0, basta exibir a linha #not-found.

Segue o código.

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr:not(:first)');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase().split(' ');
 //abaixo, salvo o conjunto resultante do filtro em $found; 
 $found = $rows.hide().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var textN = text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    var matchesSearch = true;
    $(val).each(function(index, value) {
      matchesSearch = (!matchesSearch) ? false : ~textN.indexOf(value) || ~text.indexOf(value);
  });
        return matchesSearch ; //?: $("#not-found");
  });
//aqui, vejo se houve algum encontrado, o que daria $found.length > 0 e portanto, true
  if($found.length){
      //se tem pelo menos 1, exibo as linhas
      $found.show();
 } else{
     // do contrário, exibo a linha #not-found
     $("#not-found").show();
 }
});
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

#not-found {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autofocus type="text" id="search" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  
  <tr id='not-found' ><td colspan="2">Nenhum resultado foi encontrado.</td></tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Boa, Marcos! Realmente, não tinha pensado nessa lógica tua de colocar os valores encontrados dentro da variável `found`. Muito obrigado, cara!

Comment: @winiercape Está *quase* funcionando: digite "ad" na caixa de busca pra ver o que acontece...

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso, @hkotsubo! Eu notei isso também. Ainda estou fazendo alguns ajustes no código, mas acredito que esse erro pode ser solucionado alterando esta linha: `var $rows = $('#table tr:not(:first)');` É isso?

Comment: @winiercape Eu acho que é só colocar `$("#not-found").hide()` dentro do `if($found.length)` (pois se encontrou alguma coisa, basta esconder esta linha)

Comment: Verdade! Muito melhor mesmo, @hkotsubo! Muito obrigado pelo toque!